# ffmpeg mp4 -> mp3 conversion / Browser doesn't play

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, audio, ffmpeg, mp3

I convert mp4 video files to mp3 audio, and then upload it to my server to play, with the following command:

`ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -vn -acodec libmp3lame -ac 1 -b:a 96k audio.mp3`

The resulting file plays on local computer flawlessly. However, online does not. I tried opening the Mp3 URL in Firefox (82), Chrome (86), and also in Player.FM (podcast player). Firefox plays very strange noise, the other two doesn't start playback.

ffmpeg outputs several errors when decoding:

```
ffmpeg -i http://example.com/input.mp3 -f null -
[mp3float @ 0x7efe50006880] Header missing
[mp3float @ 0x7efe50006880] invalid block type
[mp3float @ 0x7efe50006880] Error while decoding MPEG audio frame.
[mp3float @ 0x7efe50006880] big_values too big
```

I also tried to convert the resulting mp3 again with Audacity and Lame (command line). The resulting Mp3 was already playing back great in browser as well.

I want to avoid this second conversion step, if possible, and use ffmpeg to create output file which is playing back online as well.

Comment: Can't duplicate the problem. Showing the complete log from your command may show something informative.

Comment: I used this on longer videos, which I have not kept, rather uploaded to FB Watch. Right now I tried it with a short, few seconds video, and it was OK. Soon I will record a longer video and try with it again.

Comment: But I have plenty of MP3s uploaded which were converted this way and do not play back online, only offline, like this: http://binjomin.hu/audio/rasi/vajera_3.mp3

Comment: File appears damaged. Compare md5sum of local file and of upload file.

Comment: Right, interesting! There seems to be an issue with the uploading script. It interrupts without notification.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was not with ffmpeg rather with the FTP upload. The transfer was in ASCII mode instead of binary.

Comment: Mpeg audio is strange in that it has 3 versions and 3 layers. the "3" in mp3 really means layer 3. Different versions support different sample rate and bit rate combinations. When you set the bitrate, but didn't set the sample rate, the sample rate of the source file is used, and ffmpeg automatically chooses a version that works for that combination. Whatever version was used was not supported by the browser. http://www.mp3-tech.org/programmer/frame_header.html